# Why is future.get() always timing out for Volley RequestFuture?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking, android-volley

I am trying to make a synchronous Volley networking request. I am using request futures to wait on a response, but the `future.get()` call always times out (no matter how long the timeout is set to). I have tested every component individually and nothing seems to be causing the error other than my use of futures. Any ideas on what I've don wrong here?

Activity.java: persistData()

```
postCampaign(campaign);
```

Activity.java: postCampaign()

```
private boolean postCampaign(final Campaign c) {
    RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, future, future) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
            // put data
            return params;
        }
    };
    NetworkController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);

    try {
        String response = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Log.d("Volley", "" + response);
        return !response.contains("Duplicate");
    } catch (InterruptedException|ExecutionException|TimeoutException e) {
        Log.d("Volley", "[FAILED] " + e.getClass());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Strangely enough though, when stepping through the code, it appears that the RequestFuture's `onResponse` method is invoked with the appropriate response. So it seems like the RequestFuture just isn't handling the response properly.

[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are actually sending a request to the server? It looks like you are using the HTTP protocol, have you used Fiddler or Wireshark to snoop what is being sent?

Comment: When I use that same string request with different response/error listeners, the data is posted successfully and the expected response is returned. I just need to to do that synchronously (which I've had zero luck with).

Comment: Looks like you need to add request to `RequestQueue`. `RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());queue.add(request);`. Let us know if it works.

Comment: The call `NetworkController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request)` does that. It is a singleton request queue, but I have also tried replacing it with the code you suggested and I get the same result.

Comment: Not that I know a lot about Volley, but what entity is supposed to consume this queue, and what thread it uses? Have you checked that?

Comment: @Imposter I ran fiddler and confirmed that is is, in fact, making the appropriate request.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov From my understanding of it, the request queue is managed in a background thread.

Comment: I digged for a bit in Volley code on Git, and it doesn't look like you are making any glaring mistakes that might cause this. Try debugging it, place a breakpoint somewhere at method `NetworkDispatcher::processRequest` and follow response path to see where the response gets lost (if anywhere, that is).

Comment: I ran the debugger and it looks like the RequestFuture's instance data `private Request<?> mRequest` is never set during execution. Is this an issue?

Comment: So if you change the time out to something absurd like 2 minutes, it still times out?

Comment: Sounds like you can't block the UI thread. Check this out http://programminglife.io/android-volley-synchronous-request/

Comment: Alright, so I've done some more digging and it looks like the request future is receiving the response (https://imgur.com/a/huesV). The weird thing it that it still times out, regardless.

Comment: @Imposter I've tried putting it in a different thread/AsyncTask and got the same result. (I've been working on this one issue for awhile now )

Comment: @CalebWhittington, considering your investigation, you should file this as a bug in volley project.

Answer (score 1):

> I think I've come to the conclusion that either Volley is not capable of fully synchronous networking requests or at the very least it isn't worth it.

Not exactly.  You can do it but it's not in the manner that we're used to when doing synchronous network calls.

There are a couple of things you need to remember when trying to do a synchronous request in volley:

1. The synchronous request needs to run in another thread.  This is almost obvious anyway especially in recent versions of Android it will not allow you to do network calls in the main thread.
2. Once you launch that request in another thread you *cannot* block on that thread to wait for it to finish or the `future.get(...)` call fails.

so in the above example you can simply use an executor like this:

```kotlin
val campaign = ...
val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
val f = executor.execute {  
  postCampaign(campaign)
}
```

in that same strategy you CANNOT wait on the future `f` to complete by doing this:

```kotlin
f.get() // this blocks thread; your volley requests will timeout and you will be sad
```

now, you're probably asking: How do i update UI depending on the result of `future.get()` if i can't wait for it to finish?  it's simple: the magic of closure variable capture you can still use the result of `future.get()` and be able to update your UI but you do that on the main thread...with coroutines this is rather easy:

```kotlin
val response = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Log.d("Volley", "" + response);
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch { 
   // you can do whatever UI updates here based on the value of result
   binding.textView.text = result
}
```

You can also use `View::post` but it has a bit more boilerplate and less elegant/flexible than coroutines (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come to the conclusion that either Volley is not capable of fully synchronous networking requests or at the very least it isn't worth it. I ended up just showed a spinner on start and stopped it in the Volley request's `onResponse` method when the server responded with a success message. As far as the user is concerned it works the same way.